# Simplest way to isolate MOSFET from MCU

Tags: relay, inductive, spike, isolator

I want to switch a 220 V AC motor which is an inductive load with a relay which is controlled by an MCU. I've taken precautions for arcing with a TVS diode on the contacts side, but I still want to go even safer. The "Fan" tag is a GPIO pin:

[image: Schematic]

The connection between the relay and the MCU consists of the MOSFET gate and the ground. I didn't consider the +24 V because there are two power stages in between, from 24 to 5 V with a buck converter, and from 5 to 3.3 V with a linear regulator.

I've added a sort of low-pass filter (also a current limiter) to the gate, but since the grounds are connected maybe what I'm doing is trivial.

What is a simple and sufficient way to isolate the rest of the circuit from the relay and its MOSFET? Is it even necessary to consider this as long as I don't exceed the 1000 V dielectric strength of the relay?

Answer (score 6):

The relay provides isolation; all you need to worry about on the coil side is the inductive kickback, which D1 is managing. The R45/C12 combination is probably going to blow up Q1 though.

Comment: Why would anything blow up?

Comment: @CaveScientist cause that's going to slow down the switching time - you want to switch the MOSFET as fast as possible. Furthermore, you will induce chattering on the mechanical relay. What was your intention for adding a low-pass filter to the MOSFET gate?

Comment: Well, rarely if ever do you want something as fast as is *truly possible*, and a few microseconds here or there can save a lot of EMI and protection issues on slow/infrequently switching things like coil drivers.  But suffice it to say, a millisecond time constant is neither necessary nor desirable here.

Comment: I put 100 ohms resistor between every GPIO pin and seldomly switching MOSFET to limit the peak current, is this a wrong practice? I don't add capacitor ofc it is spesific to this case. The reason was to prevent any voltage spike to breach from drain to gate and harm the MCU. I guess this is not going to happen anyway, may I confidently delete the cap and resistors and put only a 100 ohms resistor?

Comment: The low-pass filter on your gate won't provide meaningful protection. Remove R45 and C12 and reduce R5 and R6 by about two orders of magnitude.

Comment: @CaveScientist Yes. delete the cap and resitors - they wouldn't help with what you described anyway - you would put the capacitor from gate to drain to absorb spikes. But still, stop trying to "low-pass filter" the gate. Makes no sense.

Comment: Done! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the answer to isolation question, because you really don't need one since relay provides all the isolation you need. This is just a comment on a schematic.

You can replace entire left side of the circuit with single relay driver chip, like [NUD3160](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nud3160-d.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to such drivers. Is there any difference between classic method and the driver besides component count?

Comment: Chips like this one provide huge space savings and also reduce the chance of beginner's mistakes thanks to their logic level inputs. I see several people already warned you about low pass filter on the gate. Well, you wouldn't even consider that if you start with this chip right away.

Comment: Also, if you look at the chip schematics in datasheet, you'd see that is is no different from what you call "classic method". Basically, it is the same ubiquitous circuit, only smart engineers already carefully selected and calculated the components for us, then put them into tiny package.

Comment: Alright thank you. Definitely helpful for small size PCBs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an opto-isolator to ensure galvanic isolation, something like a 4N28 for example.

Comment: That way, gate will be isolated but the ground of the MCU and MOSFET will still be connected. I think this contradicts the purpose of isolation.

Answer (score 1):

This looks okay to me. Watch the flow of ground currents from coil-contact coupling. Getting much benefit from an optoisolator would require a separate isolated supply for the relays (grounds not tied together).

That particular *Hongfa* relay has a pusher type construction which leads to a (decent) 4kV coil-contact isolation spec which is appropriate for this application.

Check that the contact rating is acceptable for the type of fan motor you have- I don't see a motor load rating.

Comment: I don't have datasheet of the motor but it is 30 Watts, probably not that inductive. The kickback of motor switching breached the 1000V isolation between contacts and coil of a signal type relay once when I didn't use the TVS. I guess this time the 740V clamping of TVS will not let that happen again. I asked this question because I am extra cautious now.

Answer (score 1):

Step back from this a bit. You have two things to contend with:

- Isolation at the relay itself
- Isolation between low-voltage and high-voltage wiring

Does your relay + enclosure ensure both? If so, you don’t need any further galvanic isolation. If not, then sharing a ground and power between your MCU and the relay is unsafe, and would be in violation of electrical codes.

Assuming your enclosure is safe, I would recommend a more rugged transistor in place of the 2N7002. Perhaps consider an NPN like a 2N2222.

Comment: Isolation of relay itself is good. It can resist 1000V and the TVS clamps the contact voltage to 740V. If we are sure that no parasitics will couple with the DC side when the fan is turned off then I will remove protection components.

Comment: You said nothing so far about how the wiring is actually routed. Electrical codes require that the low-voltage and high-voltage wiring be completely isolated from each other, by separate conduits, or partitioning in an enclosure, or some other means.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood completely but I'm planning to end the ground plane at some point then the AC traces start. AC traces are few and they are grouped. Connected to a terminal on the PCB. A wire is connected between the terminal on the PCB and terminal on the enclosure. I've done this many times never had an issue. The isolation between traces are no problem right? Because arching happen on the switch point. Can AC traces couple with DC traces if they are very close even though AC is just 50Hz? My AC-DC traces will probably have more than a centimeter distance but asking just in case.

Comment: It’s not about the relay or creepage distance. If your ‘hot’ AC wire comes loose from a terminal, what could it come in contact with? If your enclosure is metal, and that’s also MCU ground, then you’d be energizing your MCU with line voltage. And safety grounding the enclosure is no guarantee either - what if the external earth is faulty? Or it has some resistance (and it will). This is why you need to consider the whole setup: relay, wiring, enclosure.

Comment: Well this reply is going to make you cringe but there is no earth connection on my PCB and the box is plastic. There is no neutral connection either. A loose Line wire to DC side would blow up the power supply probably. Or maybe it would do no harm since power supply is isolated. If there is a capacitor between GND and Neutral then maybe the cap would blow up. This is another debate topic and sounds educational.

Comment: 5V relay modules with screw terminals are a common thing, especially with Arduino folks. *Every single one of them are unsafe* because, by themselves, they don’t physically isolate low voltage from high in the event a wire comes loose. All those videos and tutorials seem to gloss over that little detail. Actual products using relays (like appliances) will have physically isolated line vs. logic domains to meet UL and/or IEC approvals.

Comment: By physical isolation, what do you mean? Different PCB layers? Creepage? Air gaps?

Comment: The low voltage and high voltage sides need to be compartmentalized with an insulating barrier, such that it would be physically impossible for a loose wire to come into contact with the wrong side of things (LV DC to AC or vice-versa.)